# I want to echo out a total number per repeat

Tags: php

I have created a small script which gives me random numbers. Now I want to create a list of this random number list with repeating numbers.

It should generate match numbers of this list of random numbers (A match number is a number which repeats)
For instance 4 – 6 – 9 – 32 – 34 – 31 – 5 – 32 (The match number here is 8 because after 8 numbers we have a repeater). I would like all the match numbers to be echo beside each other with a space in between.

Can someone help me?

I have tried creating an if statement but I can't get it working.

```
for ($rnd=1;$rnd<=50;$rnd++)
{
 $random = mt_rand(0,100) . " ";
 echo $random;
}
```

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried.  You will need to store each iteration of $random in an array and match the latest $random within the created array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explanation coming soon.

```
$numbers = array();

for($i = 1; $i <= 50; $i++) {

    $number = mt_rand(0,100);
    if(!isset($numbers[$number])) $numbers[$number] = array();
    $numbers[$number][] = $i;

}

foreach($numbers as $key => $value) {

    $start = '';

    foreach($value as $k => $v) {

        echo $start . $key . ' (Match Number: ' . $v . ')';
        $start = ' - '; 

    }

    echo '<br />';

}
```

Comment: *Explanation coming soon.*, not that soon!

Comment: I think I explained it wrong. I need a list of random numbers. And from this list I want to generate a list of numbers which echo the match numbers for instance if the random numbers are: 5 - 8 - 99 - 14 - 34 - 45 - 99 the match number should be 7 since we have a match of two repeating numbers after 7 random numbers. And it should this for the whole list.

Answer (score 2):

**If I don't misunderstood your question** then this is what you want. Let's do this way-

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];
for ($rnd=1;$rnd<=50;$rnd++)
{
  $random = mt_rand(0,100);
  if(in_array($random,$existing)){
    $repeat_numbers[] = $rnd; // pushing the repeating index  
  }
  $existing[] = $random;
  echo $random.PHP_EOL;
}

echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/eEhB8

**AS PER THE COMMENT**

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];

for ($rnd=1;$rnd<=50;$rnd++)
{
  $randoms[] = mt_rand(0,100);
}
echo implode('-',$randoms).PHP_EOL;

$i = 1;
foreach($randoms as $rnd){
   if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
       $repeat_numbers[] = $i;
       $i=1;
   }
   $existing[] = $rnd;
   $i++;
}
echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO** https://3v4l.org/Xjc5X

**AS PER THE LATEST COMMENT**

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];

$randoms = explode('-','3-31-34-29-28-5-28-23-31-4-1-31-11-17-23-9-20-24-22-3-11-24-26-4-10');

$i = 1;
foreach($randoms as $rnd){
   if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
       $repeat_numbers[] = $i;
       $i=1;
       $existing = []; // This like will do the magic for you
   }
   $existing[] = $rnd;
   $i++;
}
echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/hIT22

**FINAL EDIT:**

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];
$randoms = explode('-','4-9-13-18-19-34-23-9-9-13-44-5-13-13-88-26-29-27-34-67-65-83-26');

$i = 1;
foreach($randoms as $rnd){
   if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
       $repeat_numbers[] = $i;
       $i=1;
       $existing = [];
   }else{
       $existing[] = $rnd;
       $i++;    
   }

}
echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);

?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/9j7iq

**EDITED AGAIN:**

```
<?php
$existing = [];
$repeat_numbers = [];
$randoms = explode('-','4-9-13-18-19-34-23-9-9-13-44-5-13-13-88-26-29-27-34-67-65-83-26');
//print_r($randoms);
$i = 0;
foreach($randoms as $rnd){
   $i++; 
   if(in_array($rnd,$existing)){
       $repeat_numbers[] = $i;
       if(count($existing)==1){
         $i=1;
       }else{
         $i=0;     
       }
       $existing = [];
   }
   $existing[] = $rnd; 
   //print_r($existing);
}
echo implode('-',$repeat_numbers);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/VfIJY

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196495/discussion-on-answer-by-always-sunny-i-want-to-echo-out-a-total-number-per-repea).